# System.ArgumentException: invalid JSON primitive:. but only when browsing from mobile browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization

I have a simple test responsive aspx web page, that download json data and try to display results.

If i browse from the desktop/laptop computer i do not receive any error everything is ok, json data are deserialized and data are shown (i can list results about students) but if i open via mobile browser i receive  System.ArgumentException: invalid JSON primitive:.
I dont know what can be the reason,or where to search the problem since  in one case is working as espected

Json string is like this and is very simple:

```
{
  "students":[
     {
       "studentName":"TEST- MORE TEST",
       "MoreInfo":"sdpThP5YUMsaFfwOM7tj",
       "Counter":"404",
       "Age":"20"
     }
  ]
}
```

I try to replace all dots in strings, remove all special characters and without results, i remove all records and only with one still dont work i cant figure out what can be wrong:

c# code that i use for desalinize:

```
   using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        //here i download my json data   
        string json = wc.DownloadString(download_url);

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var myStudents = jss.Deserialize<studentList>(json);

        foreach (student student in myStudents.students)
        {                
                Response.Write(student.studentName + " " + student.Age </br>");
        }
    }
```

any help appreciated, thanks

Here is how is model defined:

```
   public class student
   {
       public string studentName { get; set; }
       public string MoreInfo { get; set; }
       public string Counter { get; set; }
       public string Age { get; set; }
   }

   public class studentList
   {
      public List<student> students { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: How is your `studentList` class defined?  Also, debug your application to see what the value is of `json`, it might not be what you expect.

Comment: thanks for your response, i just edited the question

Comment: Could you dump out the `json` e.g. `string json = wc.DownloadString(download_url); Response.Write(json)`. There is something wrong with the JSON that is being downloaded via WebClient, hence the error message. There could be a difference on mobile for some reason.

Comment: Very strange if i place Response.Write(json); return in-front JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer(); on desktop is returning json string as expected, but if i try to load via mobile it redirect me to lending page of IIS8. The application is located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TESTstudent, like i said if i place Response.Write(json) and return (not to continue to JavaScriptSerializer) will display landing page from C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm if i remove Response.write will display Invalid Json primitive if i load from mobile, desktop is working ok.

Comment: It's true in mobile version i don't receive json string. I receive this:
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Pragma" />
        <title>Waiting...</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pageName = '/';
            top.location.replace(pageName);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
`